# Calculating the real power consumed in a two-port network using its S-parameters

Tags: impedance, s-parameters, esr

I would like to express the real power consumed in a two-port network using its S-parameters.

[image: Series impedance]

Assume for simplicity \$\underline{Z}=R\in\Re\$

(1) My idea was using energy conservation:
$$ P_{in} = P_{loss} + P_{refl} + P_{trans}\quad,$$
where \$ P_{in}, P_{loss}, P_{refl},P_{trans}\$, are the input power, the power that is "consumed" by the two-port (or here Z), the reflected power and the transmitted power, respectively.
Rearranging yields:
$$
P_{loss}/P_{in} = 1 - P_{refl}/P_{in} - P_{trans}/P_{in} = 1 - |S_{11}|^2-|S_{21}|^2
$$
Plugging in the corresponding values of the S matrix (\$S_{11} = \frac{Z}{2Z_0+Z}, S_{21}=\frac{2Z_0}{2Z_0+Z} \$) $$
P_{loss}/P_{in} = \frac{4Z_0Z}{(2Z_0+Z)^2}\quad
$$
which is also what I get using an expression for the real power consumed in a two-port that I found in lecture notes (I think up to a factor 2, which comes from taking the real part I guess). $$
P_{real} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{{a}}^\dagger(\overset\leftrightarrow{1}-\overset\leftrightarrow{S}^\dagger\overset\leftrightarrow{S})\vec{a}
$$,
where \$\vec{a}, \overset\leftrightarrow{1}, \overset\leftrightarrow{S},  \dagger\$ are the input vector, the identity, the S-matrix and the adjoint, respectively.

(2) However, if I look at the power consumed in the impedance Z, I could write it as $$
P_Z = U_Z \cdot I = Z \cdot I^2 = U^2\frac{Z}{(Z+2Z_0)^2}\quad
$$
where I used the voltage divider formula, and hence $$
P_Z/P_{in} = \frac{Z}{Z+2Z_0}\quad
$$
which is unequal to the expression above for \$Z\neq0\$.

(3) If I model the twoport again as a single series impedance, I could find the ESR, using the Z matrix. $$
\text{ESR} = \text{Real}(Z_{21}-Z_{11})= \text{Real}(\left.\frac{U_2-U_1}{I_1}\right|_{I_{2=0}})\quad.
$$
Using the transformation rules from Z to S matrix (from wikipedia.org) and using \$S_{11}=S_{22}, S_{21}=S_{12}^*\$ (port is symmetric for a single impedance, this again gives me another expression: $$
\text{ESR}=\text{Real}\frac{(2S_{21}-1+S_{11}^2-|S_{21}]^2)Z_0}{1+S_{11}^2-2S_{11}+|S_{21}|^2}
$$

What am I doing wrong here?
My overall goal is to find an expression of the real power consumed by an arbitrary two-port that only depends on the S-matrix, or equivalently I guess find an expression for the ESR depending on the S-matrix.

Comment: FYI, you can use `\text{}` to format text as such in math mode. For example, use `P_{\text{loss}}` to format as \$P_{\text{loss}}\$.

Comment: When getting $$
P_{loss}/P_{in} = \frac{4Z_0Z}{(2Z_0+Z)^2}\quad
$$
from $$
P_{loss}/P_{in} = 1 - P_{refl}/P_{in} - P_{trans}/P_{in} = 1 - |S_{11}|^2-|S_{12}|^2
$$ the author may have forgotten to do `abs()`, so the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't work out \$P_{in}\$ correctly:  $$P_{in} = \frac{U^2}{4Z_0}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you maybe quickly explain how you obtained this expression?

Comment: I also added a version in the question where I try to use the impedance matrix for my calculations.

Comment: It's the power dissipated in the load when your Z=0.  Look up any text on S parameters.